# Linq nested DTO expression

Tags: linq

I am new to Linq and I need help on the below.

I have the following data structure.

DTOData which is a list
Inside this is have tables and this is also list
Inside tables, I have 2 fields Name and DOB.

So my data structure looks like

DTOData1
tables1
Name
DOB
tables2
Name
DOB

DTOData2
tables1
Name
DOB
tables2
Name
DOB

I want LINQ expression to fetch the DOB based on name.

I need to loop through a list of Name and pass that as a parameter to the Linq expression.

Comment: I do not see classes, just text. And what is nested DTO expression? If you need help, spend some time for preparing good question.

Comment: the code? no one can help like this...